# Define vscode variables

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, configuration

Is there a way to define variables in vscode for use in launch.json?, I only want some variable that will be common to different configurations, let's say TESTING_USER="ABC"

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
   // it would be ideal to set it here somehow, 
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Node",
        "runtimeArgs": ["idUser", "${TESTING_USER}"],
      },
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000?${TESTING_USER}",
      }
    ],
}
```

The only solution I've found would be creating an entry in settings.json and then referring it with ${config:xxxx} but I wonder if there's a more direct way.

Comment: In the ideal situation where do you want to store this variable content

Comment: Ideally in that same launch.json, just to share some parameters among different configurations.

Comment: You can use a command from the extension to repeat its argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-key-value-pairs) and use a file with key-value pairs

Another possibility is to use the command: `extension.commandvariable.transform`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Node",
        "runtimeArgs": ["idUser", "${input:TESTING_USER}"],
      },
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000?${input:TESTING_USER}",
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "TESTING_USER",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
        "args": { "text": "ABC" }
      }
    ]
}
```